# Updating user location status on server when he enters or exits a Geofence

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, background-process, geofencing

In my application I'm using Geofencing to track whether customer is currently present in the specified location while delivering an order.Is it possible to update his status to a server when he enters or exits geofence even when the app is in background?

Comment: iOS gives you very limited time in background. So, it's not possible

Comment: @KrishnaCA Any other alternatives possible to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of location authorization you have. If you have 'always' authorization, you would be able to do it. If you have 'in-use' authorization, you would have a very small amount of time (~10s) to make the request before iOS suspends your app.

Comment: Do i need to enable background mode so that i can update the status to server when user crosses a geofence while app is in background.

Comment: No. You would not need 'always' authorization access for location just to do region monitoring and get events in background - but the application will be aggressively put to suspended state by the OS if you don't.